# Connection string in DBContext

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I want to add connection string in dbcontext file not in App config file because of security and multiple databases.i m using npgsql (.net provider for postgresql database).
here is my coding.

```
 public partial class ADBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ADBEntities()
        {
            Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder ssb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            ssb.Host = "localhost";
            //ssb.Port = 5432;
            ssb.UserName = "postgres";
            ssb.Password = "a5xxx";
            ssb.Database = "adb";
            ssb.CommandTimeout = 30;
            ssb.Pooling = true;
            ssb.MaxPoolSize = 20;
            ssb.MinPoolSize = 1;
            ssb.PreloadReader = true;
            ssb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            var cond= new NpgsqlConnection(ssb);
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = cond.ConnectionString;
        }
}
```

But it is not working and giving error "Keyword "Port" is not supported.

Comment: Could you build the string "by hand" and make it look like described [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/)? Also, if you have username/password plaintext in code then it's basically as "open" as if it was in the config file.

Comment: @Corak yes build it manually now .Program runs and when i try retrieve or save data it crash without giving me error

Comment: "crash without giving me error" - not very likely. Are you hiding exceptions (`try ... catch` with "empty" `catch`)? If not, maybe you'll find something in the windows event log.

Comment: Any luck finding the solution? I am struggling with the same problem, trying to use dynamically loaded connection string wint EF6 DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TCS3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=551680A3622135F7C7A89A2044CE6B6E_12 2014\\20 12 14\\BACKUP 19 NEW\\19 NEW\\SCHOOLMANAGEMENT\\SCHOOLMANAGEMENT\\APP_DATA\\TCS_SCHOOL.MDF;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sql2008");
```

Answer (score 0):

How does the `cond.ConnectionString` value looks like ?

Try to build yourself the connexion string with a string.Format() and set it to `this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`.